# creating a python dictionary from two pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, loops, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from two pandas dataframe following is a snapshot the dataframe which suppose to hold the keys:

```
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000007.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000009.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000009.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000009.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000009.jpg
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000012.jpg
```

And the following datarame snapshot is values for the dictionary:

```
324,339,263,211,9
253,372,165,264,9
67,374,5,244,9
295,299,241,194,9
```

so I want to append each two rows togather as a key and value in one dictionary
This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
image_files=pd.read_csv('image_files.csv')
file = pd.read_csv('Training_dataset.csv')

image_anno_dict={}

for image_file, row in zip(image_files,file.iterrows()):
    image_anno_dict[image_file]=np.array(row)
```

my expected output:

```
{'C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg': [324,339,263,211,9]
'C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg': [253,372,165,264,9]
'C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg': [67,374,5,244,9]
.
.
.
}
```

But the code work only for the first row, Any suggestion for a solution?

print(image_files.head(5)):

```
C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\000005.jpg
0  C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeprojec...                         
1  C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeprojec...                         
2  C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeprojec...                         
3  C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeprojec...                         
4  C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeprojec...
```

print(file.head(5)):

```
     0    1    2    3  4
0  324  339  263  211  9
1  253  372  165  264  9
2   67  374    5  244  9
3  295  299  241  194  9
4  312  220  277  186  9
```

Comment: Check now please, thank you

Comment: Output is expected, because dictionary has always unique keys.

Comment: Oh okay get your point, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Instead of dict, you can use a list of tuple.

Comment: This is because I have multiple objects in one picture, So I have to repeat the same picture multiple times.

Comment: @Corralien Can you show me a code sample of how to do so, and is it the same as dictionary

Comment: Just to be sure, can you update your post with the output of `image_files.head(5)` and `file.head(5)`, please?

Comment: @Corralien Check now please

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas Series to combined two dataframes and then convert it by calling to_dict method. Here is [working sample code](https://paiza.io/projects/4y5A9X_ki4JeiJ2GpCwSzw)

```
import pandas as pd

 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'df1Keys':['ab','bc','c','df','efg']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'df2Vlues':[1,25,3,84,545]})

#method 1
print(pd.Series(df2.df2Vlues.values,index=df1.df1Keys).to_dict())

#method 2
print(dict(zip(df1.df1Keys,df2.df2Vlues)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

image_files = pd.read_csv('image_files.csv', header=None)
file = pd.read_csv('Training_dataset.csv')

image_anno_list = list(zip(image_files[0], file.apply(np.array, axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
>>> image_anno_list

[('C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg',
  array([324, 339, 263, 211,   9])),
 ('C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg',
  array([253, 372, 165, 264,   9])),
 ('C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg',
  array([ 67, 374,   5, 244,   9])),
 ('C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg',
  array([295, 299, 241, 194,   9])),
 ('C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg',
  array([312, 220, 277, 186,   9]))]
```

If you use a dict, you will get this:

```
image_anno_dict = dict(zip(image_files[0], file.apply(np.array, axis=1)))
```

```
>>> image_anno_dict

{'C:/Users/Yaman/PycharmProjects/Mindsporeproject/JPEGImages_train\\000005.jpg':
 array([312, 220, 277, 186,   9])}
```